# Error in my ShinyApp on R: Non numeric matrix extent

Tags: r, shiny

Every time I try to run the shiny app on R I get this error. How to fix it?

I found out that the error is regarding `samples <- matrix(sample(1:n),ncol=K)`
But I don't understand why.

This is the code of my server:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    r=input$r
    n=input$n
    K=input$k
    sim=input$sim
    p=input$p
    noi=input$noi
    
    lsEigen0 <- replicate(1, matrix(rep(0, sim*p), 
                          nrow=sim, ncol = p), simplify=FALSE)
    
    lsmethod0 <- replicate(1, matrix(rep(0, sim*p), 
                          nrow=sim, ncol = p), simplify=FALSE)
    
    choose0 <- replicate(1, rep(0, p), simplify=FALSE)
    
    for (i in 1:sim) {
      samples <- matrix(sample(1:n), ncol=K)
      
      #df <- rmvnorm(n = n, mean = rep(0, p), sigma = diag(p)) 
      #data0 <- dataset(df,r,noi)
      
      #for (da in 1:1) {
       # lsEigen0[[da]][i,] <- svd(data0[[da]])$d
        
        #lsmethod0[[da]][i,] <- method(data0[[da]], samples)
        
        #min_err0 <- which.min(lsmethod0[[da]][i,])
        #choose0[[da]][min_err0] <- choose0[[da]][min_err0] +1
        
      #}
    }
    
    #par(mfrow=c(1,2))
    
    #plot1 = plot(1:p, colMeans(lsEigen0[[1]]), 
      xlab="kth Eigenvalue", ylab="Value", 
      main="Scree plot data set ", type = "b", pch = 19, 
       lty = 1, col = 1)
    
    #plot2 = plot(1:p, colMeans(lsmethod0[[1]]), xlab="Rank r", 
                  ylab="Value", main= "Error data set ", 
                  type = "b", pch = 19, lty = 1, col = 1)
    
    })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code runs but in the shiny app I get the error

I have tried to fix it by myself but I don't get it.

Comment: Could you also provide the `ui` code? are you sure `input$k` is numeric?

Comment: if you use a `textInput`, you need to convert it to numeric : `as.numeric(input$k)`